# how do I build a Rails (3.2) association explicitly in code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have table "parents" with about 500K entries and table "children" with about 1M entries.  "parents" has_many "children".  If I do:

`parents = Parent.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => [very large array]}, :include => [:children])`

the resulting select on "children" to build the association has explicit ids, and the number of ids is nearly as large as the number of entries in the "children" table.  (The actual select takes about two hours!)  I would like to read the entire "children" table explicitly (it's far faster, a few seconds) and explicitly associate each "children" entry with its parent so that parent.children works the usual way.

How do I do that?

===============

Thanks, Mattherick.

I was imprecise in my description because I just wanted to convey the outline of my problem, which is, I want to be able to hook up associations between Parent and Children (the names aren't important and are pseudonyms) without using the "official" Rails mechanism for find.  In other words, I want to read entries from parents and entries from children separately, then associate the child entries with their parents.

I'm using Postgres, so I'll give you the relevant pieces of the tables.  The parent table is entityversions.  The child table is dependencies.

For entityversions:

```
id                       | integer                     | not null default nextval       'entityversions_id_seq'::regclass)

"entityversions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

For dependencies:

```
id                      | integer                | not null default nextval('dependencies_id_seq'::regclass)
parent_entityversion_id | integer                | not null
...

Indexes:
    "dependencies_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_dependencies_on_parent_entityversion_id" btree (parent_entityversion_id)
```

parent_entityversion_id contains the id of the parent entityversion (of course).

So what I want to do is read a set of entityversions and *all* the dependencies, then associate the dependencies with their respective entityversions, if there is one.

And, in case I haven't made it obvious, I'm not talking about *any* changes to the database.  I want to set the in-memory associations at runtime.

Comment: Are you using indexes? Btw Rails 3.2 way would be: parents = Parents.where(:id => [very large array]).includes(:children)

Comment: Yes, we're using indexes.

Thanks for the translation to Rails 3.2. :-)

Comment: It should be Parent, not Parents in my query :-). How does your schema looks like? Tables and indexes? Can you update your question.